# RxJava1 StackOverflow Exception With Too Many Observables

Tags: java, exception, rx-java, stack-overflow

I'm working on a project using rxjava1 and I have an Observable chain that occasionally will contain thousands of observables merged or concatted together. When this happens a StackOverflow exception will occur and we will get something like this:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:631)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeToMap$ToMapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeToMap.java:127)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeFilter.java:76)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:395)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:355)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:846)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:395)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:355)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:846)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:395)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:355)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:846)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:395)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:355)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:846)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:395)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:355)
```

And the stacktrace will continue for hundreds of lines. The only related post I've seen about this is this issue in github: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3035. But the proposed solution of adding observables to a list is something we have used and doesn't work.

What can I do to prevent these StackOverflow exceptions? Do I need to do some sort of throttling or backpressuring?

Here is an example of what the current code looks like and is causing stackoverflows:

```
public Observable<Map<String, JsonObject>> extractTopLevelSummariesFromForms(JsonArray summaries, Func2<String, String, Observable<JsonObject>> summaryGatherer) {
    List<Observable<JsonObject>> summaryObservables = new LinkedList<>();
    summaries.stream()
             .map(JsonUtil::safeJsonObject)
             .filter(summary -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(summary.getString(NAME))|| StringUtils.isNotEmpty(summary.getString(Form.TITLE)))
             .forEach(summary -> {
                 if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(summary.getString(TEXT)))
                     summaryObservables.add(gatherSummariesFromElement(summary.getString(Summary.SHORT_NAME), Summary.SummaryValues.FORM,
                                                                       summary.getString(Summary.SHORT_NAME) + ".hidden",
                                                                       summary.getString(VALUE), summaryGatherer));
                 if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(summary.getString(Form.TEXT)))
                     summaryObservables.add(gatherSummariesFromElement(summary.getString(Summary.SHORT_NAME), Summary.SummaryValues.FORM,
                                                                       summary.getString(Summary.SHORT_NAME) + ".title",
                                                                       summary.getString(Summary.VALUE), summaryGatherer, true));
             });
    return Observable.merge(Observable.from(summaryObservables))
                     .filter(summaryResult -> summaryResult != null)
                     .toMap(summaryResult -> summaryResult.getString(KEY), summaryResult -> summaryResult.getJsonObject(TEXT));
}

 private Observable<JsonObject> gatherSummariesFromElement(String parentName, String parentType, String elementName, String summaryValue, Func2<String, String, Observable<JsonObject>> summaryGatherer, Set<String> visited, boolean isList) {
    if (visited.contains(elementName))
        return Observable.just(null);
    visited.add(elementName);

    Map<String, JsonObject> summariesMap = new HashMap<>();

    summariesMap.put(elementName, new JsonObject().put(Summary.SummaryValues.FORM, form).put(SUMMARY_TYPE, parentType));
    Set<String> variables = TextEngine.getVariables(summariesMap);

    Observable<JsonObject> elementSummaryObservable = Observable.just(getSummaryEntry(elementName, form, parentType, isList));

    if (variables != null && !variables.isEmpty()) {
        elementSummaryObservable = elementSummaryObservable.mergeWith(Observable.from(variables).flatMap(variable -> {
            if (StringUtils.contains(variable, ".") && StringUtils.equals(parentName, StringUtils.split(variable, ".")[0]))
                return Observable.just(null);
            else
                return summaryGatherer.call(parentName, variable).flatMap(variableEntry -> {
                    if (variableEntry == null)
                        return Observable.just(null);
                    else
                        return gatherSummariesFromElement(parentName, variableEntry.getString(SOURCE_TYPE), variable, variableEntry.getString(FORM), summaryGatherer, visited, variableEntry.getBoolean(Summary.SummaryValues.IS_LIST, false));
                });
        }));
    }
    return elementSummaryObservable;
}
```

I've tried running everything in the `Schedulers.computation()` scheduler except for network requests, those are being run in `Schedulers.io()` schedulers and I am still getting stackoverflows:

```
Exception in thread "pool-26-thread-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:59)
at rx.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorSchedulerWorker.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:107)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:355)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:846)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:395)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:355)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:846)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:395)
```

Comment: The workaround in the issue is to use `merge(Observable<Observable<..>>)` or a `PublishSubject`. What did you try exactly (code please)?

Comment: @DaveMoten The github issue says to use a list of observables or do merge with a PublishSubject. We've done the list of observables and then merged them and that's how we get the stackoverflow error. The other option, with PublishSubject, I don't think fits our needs because PublishSubject only does this: `Subject that, once an Observer has subscribed, emits all subsequently observed items to the subscriber.`

Comment: It does not say list!

Comment: help me understand what you are seeing then, because i see this as the workaround the github issue is referring to:

```List<Observable<String>> observables = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    observables.add(Observable.just("my string"));
}
Observable.merge(observables).last().toBlocking().first();```

Comment: The issue tells you to use `merge(Observable<Observable>)` not `merge(List<Observable>)` which is a different merge overload. Try `merge(Observable.fromIterable(observables))`

Comment: Please provide what you tried for the workaround because I can't imagine the workaround in issue 3035 would still fail for you unless you have still some deeply nested chains. Also make sure you modified all the places with the wrong `mergeWith` pattern.

Comment: @DaveMoten: updated with some examples

Comment: @akarnokd: updated with some examples

Comment: You have a recursion with `gatherSummariesFromElement` that may still create deep chains. Use `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())` to break the stack when you recurse.

Comment: The only Schedulers i have are: `computation`, `from`, `immediate`, `io`, `newThread`, `test`, `trampoline`, `reset`, `shutdown`, `start`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You have a recursive calls of the `gatherSummariesFromElement` which perhaps go very deeply
2. Observable.merge(Observable.from(summaryObservables)) call looks weird, you should use just Observable.merge(summaryObservables)
3. Instead of using `Observable.just(null)` and then filtering null values you may use `Observable.empty()`
4. Constructing of the `summaryObservables` looks like overkill. You may construct list of valid summaries instead of and then process them in the flatMap
5. Replace recursive Observable creation in the `gatherSummariesFromElement` with the recursive list of elements creation and then create observable from that list

_

```
public Observable<Map<String, JsonObject>> extractTopLevelSummariesFromForms(JsonArray summaries, Func2<String, String, JsonObject> summaryGatherer) {
    List<JsonObject> validSummaries = new LinkedList<>();
    summaries.stream()
            .map(JsonUtil::safeJsonObject)
            .filter(summary -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(summary.getString(NAME)) || StringUtils.isNotEmpty(summary.getString(Form.TITLE)))
            .forEach(validSummaries::add);
    Set<String> visited = new HashSet<>();
    return Observable.from(validSummaries)
            .flatMap(summary -> {
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(summary.getString(TEXT)))
                    Observable.from(gatherSummariesFromElement(summary.getString(Summary.SHORT_NAME), Summary.SummaryValues.FORM,
                            summary.getString(Summary.SHORT_NAME) + ".hidden",
                            summary.getString(VALUE), visited, summaryGatherer)));
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(summary.getString(Form.TEXT)))
                    Observable.from(gatherSummariesFromElement(summary.getString(Summary.SHORT_NAME), Summary.SummaryValues.FORM,
                            summary.getString(Summary.SHORT_NAME) + ".title",
                            summary.getString(Summary.VALUE), summaryGatherer, visited,true)));
            })
            .toMap(summaryResult -> summaryResult.getString(KEY), summaryResult -> summaryResult.getJsonObject(TEXT));
}

private List<JsonObject> gatherSummariesFromElement(String parentName, String parentType, String elementName, String summaryValue, Func2<String, String, JsonObject> summaryGatherer, Set<String> visited, boolean isList) {
    if (visited.contains(elementName))
        return Collections.emptyList();
    visited.add(elementName);
    List<JsonObject> result = new ArrayList<>()

    Map<String, JsonObject> summariesMap = new HashMap<>();

    summariesMap.put(elementName, new JsonObject().put(Summary.SummaryValues.FORM, form).put(SUMMARY_TYPE, parentType));
    Set<String> variables = TextEngine.getVariables(summariesMap);

    result.add(getSummaryEntry(elementName, form, parentType, isList));

    if (variables != null && !variables.isEmpty()) {
        for (String variable : variables) {
            if (StringUtils.contains(variable, ".") && StringUtils.equals(parentName, StringUtils.split(variable, ".")[0])) {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                JsonObject variableEntry = summaryGatherer.call(parentName, variable)
                if (variableEntry != null) {
                    result.addAll(gatherSummariesFromElement(parentName, variableEntry.getString(SOURCE_TYPE), variable, variableEntry.getString(FORM), summaryGatherer, visited, variableEntry.getBoolean(Summary.SummaryValues.IS_LIST, false));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```